# Xamarin.Forms blank App (PCL) compile errors on Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

First of all sorry for my non native English, I'm still learning.

I have problem with **Xamarin Forms** (**Visual Studio 2017** up2date).When I creating new blank cross platform application (choosing **PCL library** option while creating), the Debugger welcomes me with this **errors**:

- The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly
- Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

I searched for solutions in Stack and Xamarin forums, but still any of them solved my problem. Few days ago I **re-installed Xamarin** in Visual Studio Installer and I was able to create projects without errors. But today, when I created new project, I've got same problem as before reinstallation.

Also I tried **updating Xamarin.Forms and Android.Supportv4** in nu-get manager.

I'm new to Xamarin and really don't know what to do with these issues, so will be grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks for interesting my request.
Greetings

Comment: please do NOT post error messages as images.  Take the time to paste in the text of the error and format it.

Comment: The updates for Xamarin.Forms and Android don't play nice together. One usually rolls back the other. Make sure you're using the latest update of Xamarin Forms rather than the latest version of Android.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher I just updated Xamarin.Forms to latest stable version, but still same problem

Comment: @Marek if you create a completely new project, does that compile and run?

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher If I create completely new project I'm having issues like in main post. It doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found potential **solution**

I had my directory named like this "***#Folder Name***" and after changing to "***FolderName***" everything works fine. I think maybe Android require folders names like "***FolderName***".

Thanks for all replies.